# MediaCompat - Hook Button

Tags: android

I have the following code to capture the Hook button press from a headset. This code works in Android 4.1, Android 5.0 and also on 7.0

I have two headphones,

First one is a simple Samsung handsfree/headphones which came with an old samsung phone. It has only one button.

Second one is a Sony headphone with handsfree mic, it also has only one button.

Both these headsets when plugged in to Android 4.1 or Android 5 - the button press is recognised in the OnPlay method (see code below).

However in Android 7.1.2 when I use the Samsung Headset the onPlay method is NOT called when the Hook button is pressed.

The Sony headset button press results in onPlay method being called.

I added the commented out code to see whether a MediaButton event is being received by the application. If I use the samsung headset and press the button it does result in the MediaButton event, I verified it using the onMediaButtonEvent.

Why is this mediabutton event not translating in to onPlay - only in case of Android 7.1.2 and that too only using that particular headset.

What should I be looking in the event.

```
private void initMediaSessions()
{
    mSession = new MediaSessionCompat(getApplicationContext(), VoiceTicketService.class.getSimpleName());

    mSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS);
    mSession.setMediaButtonReceiver(null);

    mStateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY);
    mSession.setPlaybackState(mStateBuilder.build());
    mSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback()
                         {
                             //callback code is here.
                             @Override
                             public void onPlay()
                             {
                                 Log.d("onPlay", "Hook key  pressed UI is active");
                                 toggleRecogniserState();
                             }
                             @Override
                             public void onStop()
                             {
                                 Log.d("onStop", "Hook key  pressed UI is active");
                                 toggleRecogniserState();
                             }
                             @Override
                             public void onPause()
                             {
                                 Log.d("onPause", "Hook key  pressed UI is active");
                                 toggleRecogniserState();
                             }
                       /*      @Override
                             public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonEvent)
                             {
                                 KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)mediaButtonEvent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
                                 Log.d("onMediaButtonEvent ", "Hook key  pressed UI is active "+event.getAction());
                                 if(event.getAction()==0)
                                    toggleRecogniserState();
                                 return true;
                             }*/
                         }
    );
    mSession.setActive(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue using getKeycode() on the event.

The KeyCode expected for the hook button press is 79. Both the headsets send this keycode 79 when it is tested on the Android 4.1,5.0.

However  Android 7.1 is running on a Xiaomi phone which has its own Android Mod. I think this is the culprit which is recognising the button press from Samsung headphone as keycode 88 instead of 79. So its a phone specific issue and not an Android problem.